# Give an array to bluebird, call an API, then integrating the results into a single JSON output

Tags: arrays, json, node.js, promise, bluebird

## Preamble

I had a thought: What if I reduced my duplicated data structures by stringing together my objects as microservices, and why don't I use Sails, nodejs and api calls. This is where it all started.

## The problem definition

How can I send a dynamic array to a function, execute an unknown number of API calls to another microservice, then combine the returned values into a single object for processing?

## The Journey

I have found material about q or bluebird.

I have a function (in sails) that returns me a list of users email addresses in a JSON array.

```
getUserInfo: function(opt, callback){
    var https = require('https');
    var options = {
        hostname: opt.hostname || 'as.net.au',
        port: opt.port || 443,
        path: opt.path || '/developers',
        method: opt.method || 'GET',
        headers: opt.headers || {'Authorization': 'Basic ' + 'ThuperThecretKey'}
    }

    var req = https.request(options, function(res) {
        var data = '';
        res.setEncoding('utf8');
        res.on('data', function(chunk) {
            //console.log('BODY: ' + chunk); //oh so chunky
            data += chunk;
        });

        res.on('end', function() {
            //console.log(data)
            callback(null, data)
        })
    })

    req.on('error', function(e) {
        console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message)
        callback(e) //error
    })

    req.end()
}
```

It gives me back a set of email addresses in a JSON array:

```
['dev1@thisplace.com','dev2@thisplace.com','dev3@someotherplace.com']
```

and I stick this into a json object called "devs".

So now I want to pass this array to a function and have it execute an API call for every dev, and add the results into either the json object, or a new one. I assume a new one as devs is an array not a complete object.

The consensus from the Internet seems to be to use bluebird, but I am struggling with what I assume everyone struggles with, what variable is named what, which one gets updated, how to load things into the variable, where it goes, etc, etc, my head hurts. There are things going in entrances that I am not sure should be going there.

So I am asking for help. Does anyone have a example of the best way to do these asynchronously and then parse the results?

I got far enough to see a nice loop of asynchronous calls going out to my API (thats below), but how do I pass in and read a variable in the last then function?

It logged "Executing a promise for dev1@thisplace.com..... etc etc"
Then the "devs" object empty and the "dev" object as expected (each email address).

But how do I pass back to the calling json (or a new json) the output from My API call? How does it maintain and asynchronously update an object?
I assume something goes in the else after the error (Potential placeholder number 1).

Something like:

```
promise.map(devs, function(dev) {
  console.log('executing a promise for ' + dev)
  MyCont.getUserInfo({'path': '/developers' + dev}, function (err,devs) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err)
    } else {
      console.log ('devs: ' + devs)
      console.log('dev: ' + dev)
      //Potential placeholder number 1 -Some here that loads the returned value to the passed in or new array?
    }   
  })
}).then(function() {
    //Or maybe it goes here?
    console.log("done");
});
```

Comment: That question was most amusing (+1 for tickling the funny bone) but we _really_ don't want questions written like this here (-1 for the consequent editing work). Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You touched on the first obvious solution, using Bluebird's map. First thing would be to use promises everywhere:

```
// make this a Promise
getUserInfo: function(opt) {
    // your new best friend for issuing http requests without callbacks
    var request = require('request-promise');

    // the options have to change a little
    var options = {
        uri: 'https://'
               + opt.hostname || 'as.net.au' + ':'
               + opt.port || 443
               + opt.path || '/developers',
        method: opt.method || 'GET',
        headers: opt.headers || {'Authorization': 'Basic ' + 'ThuperThecretKey'}
    }

    // much shorter, right?
    return request(options);
}

devs.map(function(dev) {
    console.log('executing a promise for ' + dev)
    return MyCont.getUserInfo({'path': '/developers' + dev});
}).then(function(results) {
    // your results are here, in order
    console.log(results);
});
```

Comment: Wow, thank you for this, its an amazingly short answer. and just what I need.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume, after reading all that, your question is this:

How can I resolve an existing promise using the results of a bunch of asynchronous functions calls?

First, start with the function inside your outermost promise:

```
var processEmailAddressList = function (addresses) {
    // This is inside a promise.
    // It will return when all addresses have been processed.
    return Promise.map(addresses, processSingleAddress);
};

var processSingleAddress = function (address) {
    // How you implement this is up to you -- and up to whatever
    // promise library you are using. return a promise that resolves
    // to the value you want
};
```

Here, we are using `map`, but we could use `reduce`. There are some extremely important performance characteristics between `map` and `reduce` (see below), but I will ignore that right now. All you need to know is that you are returning a promise that will `resolve` or `reject` when all of the items in `addresses` have been processed by the callback, `processSingleAddress`.

The question is how to write `processSingleAddress`.

If you can process that single address using in a way that already uses promises, then it is simple. Maybe you are using a library that is already Promise-ready. In this case, you just call that function directly.

```
var processSingleAddress = function (address) {
    return addressProcessorWithPromise(address);
};
```

But if you cannot process your list items with promises, you need to figure out a way to do so using promises you create yourself. Here, for example, I am assuming that you are making an asynchronous call to `getDataFromAsyncProcess()` and that function takes a single address and a node-style callback.

```
var processSingleAddress = function (address) {
    // input is `sample@example.com`
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        getDataFromAsyncProcess(address, function (err, data) {
            if (err) reject(err);

            // example output is {address: 'sample@example.com', status: 'logged in'}
            resolve(data);
        });
    });
};
```

At this point, you should expect things to run like this:

```
var addresses = ['sample1@example.com', 'sample2@example.com']
processEmailAddressList(addresses)
.then(function (list) {
    // see below for the value of `list`
})
.catch(function (err) {
    console.error(err);
});
```

Inside `then`, list should now look like this:

```
[
    {address: 'sample1@example.com', status: 'logged in'},
    {address: 'samples@example.com', status: 'logged in'},
]
```

I know this looks potentially confusing with the amount of indirection that appears to be going on (functions inside functions), but welcome to JS. And the more you get used to using promises, the easier it gets.

THe last thing to be really careful about is how `map` or `reduce` (or any other promise-library iterator) does things. If you have, 5 addresses and the process is not so expensive, this is not so critical, but if you have hundreds or thousands of things to process or the processor is expensive (database calls, network requests, memory consumption, etc.), you can end up chewing up a ton of memory and killing your database if all of those addresses are processed in parallel (all at once). If this is a factor, you should try to use an iterator that does things one at a time. Consult your library API for details.

Last note: please try to keep your questions simple. That was unnecessarily verbose.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer this in such detail. Its very informative. (Keeping it short)